# Find number of nodes of a graph that cover k edges

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Given an adjacency list that represents an undirected graph I need to find the minimum number of nodes that have at least k edges. For example:
My adjacency list is
adj[1]=2, 3, 4
adj[2]=1, 5, 6
adj[3]=1, 7
adj[4]=1, 8, 9
adj[5]=2, 6
adj[7]=3
adj[8]=4, 9
         1
      /  |  \
  2    3    4
 /  \    |    /  \
5 - 6  7  8 - 9
If k=6 then the solution is 2. Nodes 2, 4 have in total 6 edges. Note that the nodes 1, 2 are not a solution since the total edges are 5, edge 1-2 is counted only one time.

Answer (score 3):

As for `k = |E|`, the problem will be a minimum vertex cover problem and is NP-Complete, you can't find any polynomial solution for the general case of `k` and general graph `G(V,E)`.